# Got a bad hardware address length for an AF_PACKET 16 8

Tags: rabbitmq, packet

We build some push notification system and we start it in docker to push messages to rabbitmq. Everything seems to work but we see some strange error or warning in the logs:

```
Got a bad hardware address length for an AF_PACKET 16 8
Got a bad hardware address length for an AF_PACKET 16 8
Got a bad hardware address length for an AF_PACKET 16 8
Got a bad hardware address length for an AF_PACKET 16 8
Got a bad hardware address length for an AF_PACKET 16 8
Got a bad hardware address length for an AF_PACKET 16 8
Connected to broker: amqp-0-9://rabbitmq:5672
```

What does this mean? How do we have to solve it?

Comment: I think it is a warning which can safely ignored. Are you having any issues?

Comment: No, no issues but I would prefer to get rid of it.